# What is the state of easyautocomplete?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

We use the js-library easyautocomplete in our projects. A few weeks ago I noticed that easyautocomplete.com is gone. Does anybody knows about the state of easyautocomplete?

Comment: Check repo: https://github.com/pawelczak/EasyAutocomplete

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @kcp: Of course I checked the repo, but the docu at the webpages was quite more verbose.

Comment: @Dieter Meemken: I try to open the page http://www.easyautocomplete.com and there is no useful content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cached version: https://web.archive.org/web/20161026014214/http://easyautocomplete.com/guide

Btw. they have opened issue about documentation:
https://github.com/pawelczak/EasyAutocomplete/issues/259